# What is the name of that pattern in java?

Tags: java, design-patterns, decorator

What is the name of that pattern in java? Please see the implementation of `RedirectAdultUserHandler1` and `RedirectAdultUserHandler2` classes.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Main().run();
    }

    private void run() {
        final List<User> users = Arrays.asList(
            new User("john", 1),
            new User("jeff", 22),
            new User("jack", 333)
        );
        UserHandler handler1 = new RedirectAdultUserHandler1(new UserHandler());
        UserHandler handler2 = new RedirectAdultUserHandler2();
        handler1.processAll(users);
        handler2.processAll(users);
    }

}

class User {
    private final String name;
    private final int age;

    User(final String name, final int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
            "name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", age=" + age +
            '}';
    }
}

class UserHandler {
    public void processAll(List<User> users) {
        users.forEach(user -> process(user, "users"));
        System.out.println();
    }

    public void process(User user, String tableName) {
        System.out.printf("%s stored into %s%n", user, tableName);
    }
}

class RedirectAdultUserHandler1 extends UserHandler {
    private final UserHandler original;

    public RedirectAdultUserHandler1(final UserHandler original) {
        this.original = original;
    }

    @Override
    public void processAll(final List<User> users) {
        original.processAll(users);
    }

    @Override
    public void process(final User user, final String tableName) {
        if (user.getAge() >= 18) {
            original.process(user, "adult_users");
        }
        original.process(user, tableName);
    }
}

class RedirectAdultUserHandler2 extends UserHandler {
    @Override
    public void process(final User user, final String tableName) {
        if (user.getAge() >= 18) {
            super.process(user, "adult_users");
        }
        super.process(user, tableName);
    }
}
```

The `RedirectAdultUserHandler1` is a decorator, but what about the `RedirectAdultUserHandler2` one? Is there some name for that?

Comment: `RedirectAdultUserHandler2` is nothing more than a subclass of `UserHandler`. It's a standard example of inheritance (`extends`) with polymorphism (`@Override`). Just basic OOP stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here not any pattern is used. `RedirectAdultUserHandler2` and `RedirectAdultUserHandler1` are subclasses of `UserHandler`. So it can be concluded that just [inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)) is used here.